# How to select posts from taxonomy in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to select posts from taxonomy in WordPress?
I need to select posts with a taxonomy parameter and add posts there that have no taxonomy set at all

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hwl_home_pagesize');
function hwl_home_pagesize( $query ) {

    if( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if( $query->is_category(7) && isset($_GET["age_id"])){
        $taxquery = array(
        'relation' => 'OR', 
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'age',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => array($_GET["age_id"]),
                'operator'=> 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'age',
                'operator'=> 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
    }
}
```

Works individually, not together

Comment: Maybe setting `field` in the second query helps?

Comment: term_id default